# Set Core-Plot annotations area

Tags: ios, annotations, core-plot

I have this:

[image]
[image]

It happens when i scroll up or right. Axes are set to be fixed (using Constraints), so when I scroll, annotations layer keeps showing until graph frame ends (it is almost on bottom of screen). Can i set annotations layer frame (or something else), so they stay inside plot area?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported automatically. You can use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot space and reposition the annotation when needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix that, if you add your annotation to your CPTScatterPlot instead of adding it to the plotArea.

I hope I could help

Linard